# Script not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

This script is working well with chrome and firefox, but not with Internet Explorer. 
Can anyone please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 170 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() != $(document).height()) {
        $("#testimonial_list").css({"position" : "fixed", "top" : "10px"});
    } else {
        $("#testimonial_list").css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : "210px"});
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's not working?  What's it doing?

Comment: it doesnt fire up in IE at all :(

Comment: Try to set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net with ur html code.

Comment: Try binding to `$(window).scroll` instead of `$(document).scroll`.

Comment: I tried using window.scroll also. I tried an alert on it. Doesnt fire up in IE

Comment: Works for me in IE9. http://jsfiddle.net/mtykm/

Comment: Anyone??? :( Actually I am trying to make the left column as fixed position and the right one scrolling. So I want the left column to be fixed only after the page has scrolled 170px. Check this link on Chrome and on IE... http://www.fluetlaw.com/testimonials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small point which might help, but don't include language="javascript" in your script declaration.

If you're using html5 you don't really need it any more along with the type attribute, but if your using xhtml trans or strict use the more basic version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Also IE has issues with top, I've used this in the past when making facebook pages you need to target the top frame not just the iframe that the html is in. This page might help you out.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I will keep this in mind. For now I just changed some settings in the internet explorer options and Bang :) it worked.

Comment: Which settings did you change ? Did doesn't seem like the kind of issue that would get fixed by changing the browser settings..